# Link + on(pagecontainershow) fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple app done with jQuery Mobile, in some point I have this:

```
    <a href="test_es.html" data-role="button">Start!</a>
```

which loads a new HTML with a lot of jquery mobile pages:

```
    <div data-role="page">
```

I have defined, in my external JS file, an global variable:

```
    var startTimeQuestion;
```

And this method, which is inside my HTML (test_es.html):

```
 <script>
     $(document).on('pagecontainershow', function() {
        console.log("Storing time..");
        startTimeQuestion = new Date().getTime();
     });
 </script>
```

The problem is that when I click on the button it loads correctly the file but it seems like it don't load the JS or the function or I don't know, because when I'm going to use my startTimeQuestion variable it says UNDEFINED and it don't show in the console the 'Storing time..'. If a reload the page, it works fine.

I have tried to do an '$.(document).ready()' function for the first time I load the page but still not working. It looks like test_es.html it isn't loading my custom.css and my test.js file until I reload completely the page. So I supposed that the error is in how I call my test_es.html, it isn't this:

```
  <a href="test_es.html" data-role="button">Start!</a>
```

the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: jQM loads external pages via AJAX by default (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation/) and only loads the first data-role="page" DIV. So you either need to move the script within the data-role="page" DIV or load the page without AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment before I found the solution, it was as simple as put the 'data-ajax' attribute to false this way:

```
 <a href="test_es.html" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Start!</a>
```